# WCF Naming Guidelines/Best Practices

Tags: wcf, naming

What are the best practices for naming WCF endpoints and methods? What are the conventions you usually follow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not aware of any specific naming conventions here - just use something "appropriate", define a standard, and stick to it :-)

If you're dealing with SOAP web services, those are typically more geared towards functions / methods - e.g. your methods would be something like `GetCustomer` or `UpdateCustomerOrder` or stuff like that. Try to come up with a consistent naming - don't use `Get....` once, `Fetch....` the other time, and `Load....` the next time. Same for saving: don't use `Save....`, `Store..` or `Put...` - settle on one and stick to it.

If you're more into the REST style of WCF - then you're dealing more with **resources**, e.g. you would have `Customer` and `Order` and `Inventory` as resources in your URL, and then use the basic HTTP verbs (`GET, PUT, POST, DELETE`) to handle the basic CRUD operations.